# NFC tags to execute commands

Tags: nfc

I would like to know if there is such a possibility to create NFC tag and then use it to execute complex commands on a tablet, for example opening a specific application or changing a certain system setting.

Is this kind of project possible to accomplish?

Comment: On a tablet that has a custom app installed or on a generic tablet without any special app instaled?

Comment: Since this project starts from scratch there is no specific tablet system setup. I would like to know about both options and decide what will suit the most.

Comment: Try using an automation app, like [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dstackexchange) or [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).

Comment: I was asking because there is no choice. An NFC tag contains a simple number or the more advanced NFC tags can be written so that you can write an URL to it. But without a special app on the device the NFC tag can trigger nothing.

Comment: So if I understand, I must create an NFC tag that will trigger an application which will execute the commands?

Comment: There are several [tag:automation] apps available, some of them support NFC directly. Also see my list of [NFC apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_nfc), which includes several matching your question.